# Distributing cards among players

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

> **Moderator Note:** This is a current contest question on [codechef.com](http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/LUCKG).

N players sit around a round table. There are $n \cdot m$ cards with unique numbers of range $1\ldots n\cdot m$.

Each player has $m$ cards. In each set of the game each player selects some card and everyone shows his card at the same time. Card of $i^{\text{th}}$ player is compared to card of player $p[i]$. If it’s number is greater than the number on card of player $p[i]$, then $i^{\text{th}}$ gets a point. $P$ is a permutation of sequence $0\ldots n-1$.

But all players when playing want this game want to win. So, we decided to give cards in such way, that each player gets a point with probability larger than $\frac{1}{2}$.

We need to tell all m cards of each of the n players playing the game.

Example : Let $n=3$ and $m=3$ and array $P$ be [2 0 1]. Then here answer is :

```
Player 0: 2 6 7
Player 1: 3 4 8
Player 2: 1 5 9
```

Here in this case each player has probability $\frac{5}{9}$.
So i need to find the distribution of these cards.

Comment: I don't understand what $P$ is for.  Since $P$ is known before the players select their cards, why not just agree that the players are rearranged so that $P[i] = i+1$?

Comment: @MJD Itjust shows that ith player card is compared with card of P[i]th player

Comment: @MJD: (a) it allow smaller cycle; (b) it's there to make the question more complicated. Since in a programming contest, anything that cause more difficulty is a chance for a program to fail, even if such difficulty is trivial mathematically.

Comment: @Gina Yeah right

Comment: This is a problem from an ongoing contest http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/LUCKG .
Kindly put this question on hold until the contest is over.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the contest has ended you can see successful submissions at https://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/LUCKG, on the sidebar to the right.